# navigationOptions in screen component is not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

If I set the **navigationOptions** in the screen component inside a **StackNavigator** to change the header of the stack  inside a **DrawerNavigator** the **navigationOptions** are not taken into account. I can however pass **defaultNavigationOptions** which are taken into account. If I don't pass **defaultNavigationOptions** it doesn't change the behavior. This is with react-navigation v 4.x

here I create the Stack navigators screens for my Drawer

```
  drawerNavigator = () => {
    let drawerRoutes = {}
    this.state.routes.forEach(r => {
      let stackRoute = {}
      let t = () => <First name={r} />
      stackRoute[r] =  { screen : t }
      let stackOptions = {
        initialRouteName: r,
        defaultNavigationOptions: stackNavigationOptions
      }
      let s = createStackNavigator(stackRoute, stackOptions)
      drawerRoutes[r] = { screen : s }
    })

    let drawerOptions = {
      drawerWidth: '75%',
      initialRouteName: this.state.routes[0],
      contentComponent: props => <Menu {...props} />,
      contentOptions: drawerItemsOptions
    }
    return createDrawerNavigator(drawerRoutes, drawerOptions);
  }
```

Then in my component I try to set the **navigationOptions** of the Stack but it is not taken into account...

```
export default class First extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: 'hahahaha',
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button
          onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
          title="Info"
          color="#fff"
        />
      ),
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <StatusBar transluscent backgroundColor="transparent" barStyle="dark-content" />
        <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've discovered that if I pass my screen that way

```
stackRoute[r] =  { screen : First }
```

instead of the

```
let t = () => <First name={r} />
stackRoute[r] =  { screen : t }
```

the navigationOptions are taken into account. However I cannot pass props that way....